# How to redirect the user to another tab panel in the same page? ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am implementing an authentication page which contains an `<AppBar>` with two `<TabPanel>`s. I want to redirect the user to login tab after submitting his information in register tab. I have searched for this problem, but I could not find a solution.

Here is my code in **App.jsx**:

```
function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/authentication" element={<Authentication />}/>
          </Routes>

        </div>
    
  </Router>
  );

}

export default App;
```

Authentication component:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Login from "./Login/Login";
import Signup from "./SignUp/Signup";

function TabPanel(props) {
    const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

    return (
        <div
            role="tabpanel"
            hidden={value !== index}
            id={`full-width-tabpanel-${index}`}
            aria-labelledby={`full-width-tab-${index}`}
        {...other}
        >
            {value === index && <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>{children}</Box>}
        </div>
    );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

function a11yProps(index) {
    return {
        id: `full-width-tab-${index}`,
        "aria-controls": `full-width-tabpanel-${index}`,
    };
}

export default function Authentication() {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };
    const handleChangeIndex = (index) => {
        setValue(index);
    };
    return (
        <div className="auth">
        <Box
            className="Mui-login-box"
            sx={{ bgcolor: "background.paper", width: 500 }}
        >
            <AppBar sx={{ backgroundColor: "#E55405" }} position="static">
            <Tabs
                value={value}
                onChange={handleChange}
                // indicatorColor="secondary"
                variant="fullWidth"
                TabIndicatorProps={{
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: "#1A237D",
                },
                }}
            >
                <Tab
                    style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 18 }}
                    label="Register"
                    {...a11yProps(0)}
                />
                {/*signup*/}
                <Tab
                    style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 18 }}
                    label="Login"
                    {...a11yProps(1)}
                />
            </Tabs>
            </AppBar>

            <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
                <Signup />
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
                <Login />
            </TabPanel>
        </Box>
        </div>
);
}
```

And this is my signup component:

```
const Signup = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
        username: "",
        showPassword: false,
        showConfirmPassword: false,
    });

    const [firstnameError, setFirstnameError] = useState(false);
    const [lastnameError, setLastnameError] = useState(false);
    const [emailError, setEmailnameError] = useState(false);
    const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState(false);
    const [cofirmPasswordError, setCofirmPasswordError] = useState(false);
    const [usernameError, setUsernameError] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
        if (prop === "confirmPassword" && event.target.value !== values.password)
            setCofirmPasswordError(true);
        else if (
        prop === "confirmPassword" &&
        event.target.value === values.password
        )
        setCofirmPasswordError(false);
        if (prop === "firstname") setFirstnameError(false);
        if (prop === "lastname") setLastnameError(false);
        if (prop === "password") setPasswordError(false);
        if (prop === "username") setUsernameError(false);
        if (prop === "email") setEmailnameError(false);

        setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
    }

    const handleClickShowPassword = () => {
            setValues({
            ...values,
            showPassword: !values.showPassword,
            });
    };

    const handleClickShowConfirmPassword = () => {
        setValues({
        ...values,
        showConfirmPassword: !values.showConfirmPassword,
        });
    };

    const handleMouseDownPassword = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    const onSignup = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!values.password) setPasswordError(true);
        if (!values.username) setUsernameError(true);
        if (!values.confirmPassword) setCofirmPasswordError(true);
        if (!values.firstName) setFirstnameError(true);
        if (!values.lastName) setLastnameError(true);
        if (!values.email) setLastnameError(true);

        if (values.password && 
            values.username && 
            values.confirmPassword &&
            values.firstName &&
            values.lastName &&
            values.email) {
                setFirstnameError(false);
                setLastnameError(false);
                setEmailnameError(false);
                setPasswordError(false);
                setCofirmPasswordError(false);
                setUsernameError(false);
                axios({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/accounts/register/",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    data: {
                        first_name: values.firstName,
                        last_name: values.lastName,
                        email: values.email,
                        password: values.password,
                        password_again: values.confirmPassword,
                        username: values.username
                    }
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    window.location="/home/Dashboard/"
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    toast.error("Unexpected error has occurred", {
                        position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_LEFT,
                        autoClose: 5000,
                        hideProgressBar: false,
                        closeOnClick: true,
                        pauseOnHover: true,
                        draggable: true,
                        progress: undefined,
                        theme: 'dark',
                    })
                })
            }

    }
    return (
        <div>
        {/* <div className="authLogo">
            <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
        </div> */}
        <div className="authLogoLabel" style={{ marginBottom: "1rem"}}>
            <h1>
                Welcome to <b className="NJText">Nomad Journey</b> !
            </h1>
        </div>
        <Box
            component="form"
            sx={{
            "& .MuiTextField-root": { m: 1, maxWidth: "100%" },
            }}
            noValidate
            autoComplete="off"
        >
            <form
            id={"Signup-Form"}
            onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                onSignup();
            }}
            >
            <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
                <TextField
                    error={firstnameError}
                    helperText={firstnameError ? "Enter your firstname!" : ""}
                    id="outlined-adornment-firstname"
                    type={"text"}
                    value={values.firstName}
                    onChange={handleChange("firstName")}
                    label="Firstname"
                />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
                <TextField
                error={lastnameError}
                helperText={
                    lastnameError ? "Enter your lastname!" : ""
                }
                id="outlined-adornment-lastname"
                type={"text"}
                value={values.lastName}
                onChange={handleChange("lastName")}
                label="Lastname"
                />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
                <TextField
                error={usernameError}
                helperText={
                    usernameError ? "Enter a username!" : ""
                }
                id="signup-outlined-adornment-username"
                type={"text"}
                value={values.username}
                onChange={handleChange("username")}
                label="Username"
                />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
                <TextField
                error={emailError}
                helperText={
                    emailError ? "Enter a valid email!" : ""
                }
                id="signup-outlined-adornment-email"
                type={"text"}
                value={values.email}
                onChange={handleChange("email")}
                label="Email"
                />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
                <TextField
                error={passwordError}
                helperText={
                    passwordError ? "Peek a valid password!" : ""
                }
                id="outlined-adornment-password"
                type={values.showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                value={values.password}
                onChange={handleChange("password")}
                InputProps={{
                    endAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment>
                        <IconButton
                            aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                            onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                            onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                            edge="end"
                        >
                        {values.showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
                        </IconButton>
                    </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                }}
                label="Password"
                />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
                <TextField
                error={cofirmPasswordError}
                helperText={
                    cofirmPasswordError ? "Confirm password is not valid!" : ""
                }
                id="outlined-adornment-confirmPassword"
                type={values.showConfirmPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                value={values.confirmPassword}
                onChange={handleChange("confirmPassword")}
                InputProps={{
                    endAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment>
                        <IconButton
                        aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                        onClick={handleClickShowConfirmPassword}
                        onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                        edge="end"
                        >
                        {values.showConfirmPassword ? (
                            <VisibilityOff />
                        ) : (
                            <Visibility />
                        )}
                        </IconButton>
                    </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                }}
                label="Password confirmation "
                />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
                <Button
                    sx={{ m: 1 }}
                    onClick={onSignup}
                    variant="outlined"
                    size="large"
                    type="submit"
                >
                Submit
                </Button>
            </FormControl>
            </form>
        </Box>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Signup
```

And this the output:

[image]

I will be grateful for any help on how to redirect the user automatically to Login panel after clicking on submit button.

**Update:**

I have changed my codes based on @kofeigen answer.

In my **App.jsx** file:

```
<Routes>
       <Route exact path="/authentication/:tabIndex" element={<Authentication />}/>
              
</Routes>
```

And I have added `tabIndex` parameters to both `<Tab>`s in **Auth.jsx** file, with the required `useEffect` function:

```
export default function Authentication() {
    const { tabIndex } = useParams();
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };
    const handleChangeIndex = (index) => {
        setValue(index);
    };


    React.useEffect( () => {
        setValue( tabIndex );    
    }, [ tabIndex ] );

    return (
        <div className="auth">
        <Box
            className="Mui-login-box"
            sx={{ bgcolor: "background.paper", width: 500 }}
        >
            <AppBar sx={{ backgroundColor: "#E55405" }} position="static">
            <Tabs
                value={value}
                onChange={handleChange}
                // indicatorColor="secondary"
                variant="fullWidth"
                TabIndicatorProps={{
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: "#1A237D",
                },
                }}
            >
                <Tab
                    component={Link}
                    tabIndex={0}
                    style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 18 }}
                    label="Register"
                    {...a11yProps(0)}
                />
                <Tab
                    component={Link}
                    tabIndex={1}
                    style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 18 }}
                    label="Login"
                    {...a11yProps(1)}
                />
            </Tabs>
            </AppBar>

            <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
                <Signup />
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
                <Login />
            </TabPanel>
        </Box>
        </div>
);
}
```

And finally in **Signup.jsx**, I changed the `window.location` like this:

```
.then((res) => {
                 let tabIndex = 1;
                 window.location=`/authentication/${tabIndex}`;
               })
```

But Now when I go to `http://localhost:3000/authentication` address nothing is not shown. And when I go to `http://localhost:3000/authentication/0` only a white box is shown.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible using URL parameters and React.useEffect.

In the **Signup** component, when the `onSignup` callback resolves from the asynchonous call to */api/v1/accounts/register*, the code:

```
.then((res) => {
    window.location="/home/Dashboard/"
})
```

...could be changed to...

```
.then((res) => {
    window.location=`/home/Dashboard/${tabIndex}`;
})
```

...where *tabIndex* could defined as a variable (e.g. 1 or 0 or something else) based on the outcome of the attempted sign up. Below, `tabIndex` is set to `1` to represent a successful sign up.

Now that the URL has a parameter you will need to extract the parameter and apply it to the `/authentication` path in **App** (i.e. `/home/Dashboard/1` needs to result in targetting `/authentication/1`) and use it in the **Authentication** component. If using React Router this might involve using the `useParams` hook in `<Authentication />`. **Authentication** would also need to call `React.useEffect` to update `value` with the new tab index.

For example:

### App

```
...

<Route exact path="/authentication/:tabIndex?" element={<Authentication />}/>

...
```

### Authentication

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

...

const { tabIndex } = useParams();

React.useEffect( () => {
    if ( 0 == tabIndex || 1 == tabIndex ) {
        setValue( parseInt( tabIndex ) );    
    }
}, [ tabIndex ] );


....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I want to go to login component after a successful sign up. So I think we should say in `then((res) => { window.location=/authentication/${tabIndex};}`, in which `tabIndex = 1`, am I right?

Comment: I have edited my question and added the things which you have said. May you please take a look at it?

Comment: Actually at first I have defined a route only for `/authentication` address. Ok I will upload my whole code.

Comment: One thing is that we now need to handle the case when `Authentication` is used with an undefined `tabIndex`. This could be the problem you are seeing now.

Comment: This is a [link](https://github.com/AylinNaebzadeh/Authentication) to my authentication page codes.

Comment: No it still does not work:( and when I go to `http://localhost:3000/authentication` address nothing is not shown. Something that I want is that to redirect the users after submitting their information in signup tab to login tab. I wish my explanation to be clear.

Comment: Yes, I am so sorry, I have deleted extra and useless codes, and now everything works fine. May you please check it again?

Comment: Yes, my problem was solved by changes which you have mentioned in your pull request.

Comment: Great. I removed unnecessary comments and updated my answer.